# Copy jar files to local folder

Tags: powershell, copy, copy-item

I have in a folder some JAR files generated by Maven.

I tried to copy **only JAR files** to another path with PowerShell using this command:

```
Copy-Item -Path C:\jenkins\workspace\maven-test\target\*.jar -Destination C:\jenkins\extlib -Recurse
```

But the result is a file called `extlib` without extension in `C:\Jenkins`.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `extlib` doesn't already exist as a subfolder of `C:\Jenkins` and you specify the destination path without a trailing backslash PowerShell will copy all files to the destination *file* `C:\Jenkins\extlib`, replacing each copied file with the next one.

Adding a backslash to the end of the destination path will make PowerShell throw an error if the folder doesn't exist:

```cs
$src = 'C:\jenkins\workspace\maven-test\target'
$dst = 'C:\jenkins\extlib'

Copy-Item -Path "${src}\*.jar" -Destination "${dst}\" -Recurse
```

To avoid this issue entirely create a missing folder before copying the files:

```
$src = 'C:\jenkins\workspace\maven-test\target'
$dst = 'C:\jenkins\extlib'

if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $dst -PathType Container)) {
    New-Item -Type Directory $dst | Out-Null
}
Copy-Item -Path "${src}\*.jar" -Destination "${dst}\" -Recurse
```